# Is there a solution for resizing the image to compare it with a dataset in pyqt5?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to open an image and compare it with a dataset to tell the type of the image.
so the size of the loaded image should be the same as the images from the dataset

I tried writing a function to resize the image before comparing it with the dataset but it doesn't work and shows an error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize

here's the code for loading the image and then prepare it to be compared to the images from the dataset:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__()
        loadUi('Main_GUI.ui',self)
        self.open_button.clicked.connect(self.browsimages) # adding the funtionality of the "open_button" button , and then create a function named brownimages
                                                    # the above code is something like that: when the Open button is clicked go to function browsimages and do it
        self.predict_button.clicked.connect(self.predict)

def browsimages(self):
    fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Select Image", "", "Image Files (*.png *.jpg jpeg "
                                                                                  ".bmp)")
    if fileName:
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(fileName)
        pixmap = pixmap.scaled(self.imageLbl.width(), self.imageLbl.height(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.imageLbl.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.imageLbl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

def predict(self):

    filepath = self.image_name.text

    def prepare(filepath):
        IMG_SIZE1 = 64  # 50 in txt-based
        IMG_SIZE2 = 64  # 50 in txt-based
        img_array = cv2.imread(str(filepath))  # read in the image, convert to grayscale
        new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE1, IMG_SIZE2))  # resize image to match model's expected sizing
        return new_array.reshape(-3, IMG_SIZE1, IMG_SIZE2, 3)  # return the image with shaping that TF wants.

    model = tf.keras.models.load_model("flowers99.model")
    predictions = model.predict([prepare(self.image_name.text)])

    result = np.where(predictions[0] == 1)

    if result[0] == 0:
        self.Prediction_Result.setText("daisy")
    elif result[0] == 1:
        self.Prediction_Result.setText("dandelion")
    elif result[0] == 2:
        self.Prediction_Result.setText("rose")
    elif result[0] == 3:
        self.Prediction_Result.setText("sunflower")
    else:
        self.Prediction_Result.text("tulip")
```

Where in the "browsimages" the image should be loaded then when pressing predict it showed compare it with the dataset and then determine its type.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2c0d.png)

**The error statement:**
"

```
I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
    To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:146] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
    <class 'cv2.error'> OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-kh7iq4w7\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4051: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'
     <traceback object at 0x000001EE804E90C0>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:/gui_program/main.py", line 48, in predict
        predictions = model.predict([prepare(self.image_name.text)])
      File "D:/gui_program/main.py", line 44, in prepare
        new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE1, IMG_SIZE2))  # resize image to match model's expected sizing
    cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-kh7iq4w7\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4051: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'


Process finished with exit code 1
```

"

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with Qt but from another part of your application.

Comment: I tested the AI model and it's working fine!
the issue in the method prepare, can u please help me fix it?

Comment: The big question: what is `image_name`?  That is, where have you defined it? Also improve your indentation.

Comment: The 'image_namd' is the label that is on top of the image which tell it's name